# function viewholder class in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

What is the function of the viewholder class  in `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public View mView;
            public TextView textView;

            //Constructor
            public ViewHolder(View v) {

                super(v);
                textView = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                mView = v;
            }
        }
```

I don't understand what the function of this code is, what does it make possible and for what is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this class a non-static outer class because the entities of this class are usually accessed via holder object that you will find in onBindViewHolder() of recycler view adpater and equal number of objects of this class are created as the number of objects of items are created and this class is used to inflate,add and to access every items of recylerview.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a function, it is an inner static class with a single Constructor, you need just perform all needed actions on its creation (e.g. v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)) and then it will be passed to your RecyclerView adapter